# Is mozzarella liquid affected by the no fluids policy on planes?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, food-and-drink

Recently I heard a story of a friend who was flying from Rome to Berlin. He tried to carry a big mozzarella cheese with him. Mozzarella cheese is generally layered in a milky liquid.

At the security check he was told to open the box with the mozzarella cheese and the officer told him that he is not allowed to take the cheese on the plane, because the liquid is more than 100ml.

Is this really possible? Is mozzarella liquid affected by the "no fluid" policy on planes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest comparison I can think of is baby food, which is indeed restricted. [According to IATA TravelCentre](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/iata-travellers-faq.htm):

> The International Civil Aviation Organisation, the UN’s aviation
>   standard-setting body, has defined guidelines that more and more
>   governments are adopting. The current restrictions **for liquids,
>   aerosols and gels** from ICAO and in effect in most many countries are
>   that they must be in containers 100ml or equivalent, placed in a
>   transparent resealable plastic bag with max capacity 1-litre. At
>   screening, plastic bags should be presented apart from other carry on
>   items.

UK's DirectGov website further elaborates that ['liquids' are](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/TravelAndTransport/Publictransport/AirtravelintheUK/DG_078179):

> - all drinks, including water, soup and syrups
> - cosmetics and toiletries, including creams, lotions, oils,
>     perfumes, mascara and lipsticks
> - sprays, including shaving foam, hairspray and spray deodorants
>        pastes, including toothpaste
> - gels, including hair and shower gel
> - contact lens solution
> - **any other solutions and items of similar consistency**

Based on the final point in the list, it does appear that airport security might have some ground for preventing carriage of, in this case, mozarella cheese if has milky fluid in the same container.

Comment: Mozzarella itself can be considered as a gel, and therefore be banned with or without its liquid.